# Target iFrame after customized google form submit in Safari

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, submit, target

I created a google form where I took the code to customize the form into a website.
My problem is when I want to submit the form, I redirect users to a page called "thankyou.php"  after submitting it, but it doesn't work in Safari 5 and 6, only in 7 on Mavericks.

First I've got an hidden iFrame that one loaded and the form submitted redirect to the thankyou page

```
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" 
onload="if(submitted) {window.location='thankyou2.php';}"></iframe>
```

Here is for my form html tag below

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/a/utoolize.com/forms/d/13fs7NNJTefFO0X0IzISEyDV0tTd6lV1JJbP_c5d9G14/formResponse" 
method="POST" id="ss-form" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
```

And my submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit">
```

I already tried to display block the iFrame but it doesn't work.

It would be very awesome to help me with that, thank you so much :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I seem to be having the same issue with Sarai 6.

Comment: Sorry Brian I never figured it out, I had to find another solution for these browsers unfortunately.